gdb attach to an argument passed by a pipe failed
I can use
gdb attach 45432

to debug a process. However, when I use
echo 45432 |xargs gdb attach

the gdb attached successfully, but then print
(gdb) quit
A debugging session is active.
Inferior 1 [process 45432] will be detached.

Actually I use ps -ef with some greps to get that 45432. So how can I deal with the problem?

Though it does not solve your detach issue, the right way to attach is echo 45432 | xargs gdb -p.

Looks like you need to run xargs with --open-tty option. This worked for me:
echo 45432 | xargs --open-tty gdb -p

See man xargs:
   -o, --open-tty
          Reopen stdin as /dev/tty in the child process before exe‐
          cuting the command.  This is useful if you want xargs to
          run an interactive application.

